# How To Merge Multiple Groupby Dataframes and Change Column Names--Getting NAs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

Just to give some context I'm just learning python and coding. We've been given data on the Titanic. I've search the web for an answer and couldn't exactly find what I was looking for. So that's why I'm asking now.

We need find the survival rate by class. And then return an output of the data.

I want to create a Dataframe that has the class as row names and the columns of "Average" and "Count" meaning the average survival rate of each class and the count of surviving individuals.

I know I could just do the groupby function and print it--which does give me a nice enough output. I recognize that's a possibility and did produce that initially. But I would like a "table" like appearing output with everything nicely listed in columns with the rows labelled by class.

I understand I could create a new data frame and retype the numbers given from my initial outputs. But I don't think that's quite efficient or could be expanded easily to larger data sets.

So this was my initial code

```
Survival_Class_Avg = pd.DataFrame(titanic.groupby(["pclass"])["survived"].mean())
Survival_Class_Count = pd.DataFrame(titanic.groupby(["pclass"])["survived"].count())

Surivval = pd.DataFrame(Survival_Class_Avg.copy().merge(Survival_Class_Count.copy(), how = "left", left_on = "pclass", right_on = "pclass"))
```

[This is the table it produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cHI5.png)

But I'd like to add column names of Average and Count (maybe Passenger Class depending on if I use "as_index = false". But when I do, it get NaN in my columns.

```
Surivval = pd.DataFrame(Survival_Class_Avg.copy().merge(Survival_Class_Count.copy(), how = "left", left_on = "pclass", right_on = "pclass"), columns = ["Average", "Count"])
```

[This is the table filled with NaNs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVzu6.png)

I have also tried:

```
Survival_Class_Avg = pd.DataFrame(titanic.groupby(["pclass"], as_index = False)["survived"].mean())
Survival_Class_Count = pd.DataFrame(titanic.groupby(["pclass"], as_index = False)["survived"].count())

Surivval = pd.DataFrame(Survival_Class_Avg.copy().merge(Survival_Class_Count.copy(), how = "left", left_on = "pclass", right_on = "pclass"), columns = ["Class","Average", "Count"])
```

which also doesn't change much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need join for this case, instead you can do:

```
titanic.groupby(["pclass"])["survived"].agg(['mean', 'size'])
```

Comment: That helps! Thanks!